# Qu'est ce que « ceusses » veut dire et comment est-il utilisé?

Tags: expressions, pronoms, sens

Que veut dire la phrase

> « Ah, que les ceusses d'aujourd'hui fussent aussi grands que les ceusses d'hier ! »

Contexte : pendant une conversation ailleurs, j'ai fait part de ma surprise à l'existence de groupes de défense du subjonctif imparfait, et de ce que ce fait m'amuse bien. Quelqu'un a répondu avec cette phrase. Quelqu'un d'autre trouvait que « ceusses » n'est pas français.

Alors, mes autres questions (sur le chemin d'une réponse à la question ci-dessus) :

1. Est-ce que « ceusses » est un mot Français?
2. D'où vient-il?
3. Comment utilise-on ce mot?

Comment: @Otiel honnêtement, je n'ai pas exactement sûr, non. Ma langue maternelle est Anglais; ce mot a été mentionne par quelqu'un qui est couramment. J'ai trouvé [un définition ici](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ceusses) mais je ne le comprends pas le sens même après ayant lu ce page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bon, c'est compliqué.

« Ceusses » est au départ du français volontairement incorrect, qu'on ne trouve quasiment que dans la locution « les ceusses », dont l'équivalent grammaticalement correct est « ceux ». On la rencontre souvent dans une expression figée :

> Les ceusses d'aujourd'hui ne sont pas aussi grands que les ceusses d'hier.

C'est une expression presque proverbiale, surtout orale (même si je suis étonné de ne voir apparaître [aucune occurrence sur Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22que+ceux+d%27hier%22) — heureusement que ce vide va être comblé derechef). Elle caricature le regret fréquent pour le passé, les phrases du type « les [groupe nominal] d'aujourd'hui ne sont pas aussi [adjectif laudatif] que ceux d'hier ».

« Les [ceusses](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ceusses) » est plus généralement une expression familière qui veut dire « les gens ». C'est une expression avant tout orale mais [qui a bien fait son entrée à l'écrit](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22les+ceusses%22).

La deuxième partie de cette phrase, c'est l'utilisation de l'[imparfait du subjonctif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imparfait_du_subjonctif). Ce temps a quasiment disparu de la langue courante, on utilise le subjonctif présent à la place. L'imparfait du subjonctif est aujourd'hui réservé à la langue soutenue et paraît hypercorrect lorsqu'on l'utilise à l'oral<sup>1,2</sup>.

> *Je veux qu'il vienne.* (présent)
>   *Je voulais qu'il vienne.* (passé, langage courant)
>   *Je voulais qu'il vînt.* (passé, langage soutenu)

La phrase mélange donc une expression familière essentiellement orale avec une tournure soutenue.

¹ 
<sub>Sauf De Gaulle, un ceusse d'hier plus grand que les ceusses d'aujourd'hui, qui le faisait bien passer.</sub>

² 
<sub>Ce que regrettent les ceusses qui créent des associations de défense du subjonctif imparfait.</sub>

Comment: Et par *plus grand* on entend *un mètre quatre-vingts-treize*.

Comment: @Evpok: ceci me rappelle une anecdote (amusante, donc probablement fausse) à propos de Napoléon. L'Empereur avait accroché son chapeau à un arbre alors qu'il était à cheval. Une fois descendu, il ne pouvait plus le reprendre. Un grenadier de la Garde (5 pieds 6 pouces [français] de taille minimale réglementaire) vient à son secours et lui rend son chapeau en s'excusant d'être grand. L'Empereur répondit : "Non, Monsieur, moi, je suis grand. Vous, vous êtes _haut_."

Comment: Aussi au [TLFi, I. B.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ceux), sous _ceux de_. Ici j'ai déjà entendu _ceuses-là_ (avec le son z), je pense que c'était pour _celles-là_, un truc basilectal sans doute. Merci !

Comment: derechef [dəʀəʃɛf] adv. ÉTYM. 1138, de rechief ; comp. de de, re-, et chef au sens de « bout, fin ». ◆ Vx ou littér. Une seconde fois ; encore une fois. ➙ Nouveau (de nouveau). © 2017 Dictionnaires Le Robert - Le Grand Robert de la langue française => et non "immédiatement"

Comment: @Frmwa Ah tiens, le Robert n'est pas à jour. Si tant est que *derechef* est encore utilisé, c'est plus souvent dans le sens d'« immédiatement ». Voir [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/derechef), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/derechef).

Answer (score 0):

Uniquement sur *ceusses*. Il s'agit (d'une variante orthographique) du pronom démonstratif masculin pluriel (*ceux*), substantivé. Comme pronom il forme avec d'autres mots un syntagme nominal ; comme nom il désigne essentiellement *des [personnes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ceusses#Nom_commun)*. On le trouve dans un dictionnaire régional (du Québec) d'il y a un siècle ([GPFC](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf)) :

[image]

En résumé *les ceusses/ceuses* tient pour *(les) ceux*, qui est simplement « ceux ». On l'identifie aussi [au FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/51181), à tout le moins d'origine picarde, et on y réfère au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/celui) :

> Dans la langue populaire ou vulgaire, le démonstratif, qui a lui-même
> une forme particulière, est volontiers précédé d'un article défini.
> *Les ceusses de là-bas* (Genevoix, *Raboliot*, 1925, p. 327).

Il n'est pas régulier aujourd'hui de l'employer couramment comme équivalent de *(les) ceux*, comme on l'évoque [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1660/25619), et ça fait archaïsant et/ou basilectal (ce qui peut être le but recherché dans un l'emploi).